# How to send email with attachment using GmailSender in android

Tags: android

I want to know about how to send email with attachment using GmailSender in android.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/android-send-email-via-gmail-actually-via-smtp/) example code?

Comment: this this link for file attachment for perfect working\ [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005983/sending-email-with-attachment-through-gmailsender/6222546#6222546][1]

Answer (score 3):

this is gmailsender,but i want to get flag when username and password enter by user and check from gmail db that user is valid or not.

Comment: you can authenticate over smtp/pop as gmail allows both protocols.. otherwise you can go for open id auth but it cannot guarantee the mailbox.. it verifies just google account.