# How to Attach FIles Through Mail in android

Tags: android, gmail, attachment

hi first of all i want to say an using gmail sender To send mails on a button click in my app  where i got [Solution From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a)

now in the above code i cant attach files .but later i have seen a solution from Stack over flow to solve this in that there was some modification done in the "GMailSender.java" file the modified  link is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005983/sending-email-with-attachment-through-gmailsender?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

how ever there is Addition portion to attach file now my problem is that i don't understand the modified portion. **here is the old portion**

> public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients)

**the modified portion is**

> public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients, File attachment)

this is not a duplicated question i just want to know What this "File attachment" portion is and what type or method should i implement to attach a file  if you have any doubt please go through these Two links and  please find the solution thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a `File` object called `attachment`. That will be whatever you want to attach to your email.

You would attach it to your email message like:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
message.setSubject(subject);

MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
mbp1.setText(body);

MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();
FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(attachment); //set attachment to filedatasource
mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds)); //add the filedatasource object to your 2nd mimebodypart
mbp2.setFileName(fds.getName());

Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
mp.addBodyPart(mbp1); 
mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);

message.setContent(mp);
...send email...
```

Edit: Never had to get an image from the SD card, but I think you can easily create a `File` object of it like this:

```
File imageFile = new File("path to image on sd card");
```

Then you would call your sendMail method passing in that file object.

Comment: i dont understand that how to can i  attach a jpeg file

Comment: Where are you pulling the jpeg from?

Comment: a picture file from mycomputer  to the virtual memory card on my emulator

Comment: how will i specify the file that has been pull to the mnt

Comment: bschultz did you get my answer for your question bro please help

Comment: So you're getting the image from the SD card and need to know how to set it to your File object?

Comment: my image on mnt its is gg.jpg how will i specify the path is there any particular method to implement the path

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on Data Storage in Android http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal That should give you some insight on how to get the path to your image. I know File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); will give you the path to the SD card.

Comment: File imageFile = new File("/sdcard/ss.jpg"); this is the methord by which we specifty the path thankyou once again well done

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
i.setType("message/rfc822") ; // use from live device
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@gmail.com"});  
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject goes here");  
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"body goes here");  
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, new File(""));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select email application."));
```