# send mail with MS Excel file (from sdCard) attachment programmatically in android

Tags: android, sendmail, attachment

after a few researches I managed to send emails programmatically from my app directly by following those steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124) and without launching any mails app

but now I want to add a MS Excel file as attachment

and I don't know how

as I have understood from this code:

```
   public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

I call the above method in a background asynctask to send the message but is there any way to add MS Excel file attachment

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/268122/Send-email-with-attachment-by-android

Answer (score 0):

Modified function with file parameter (credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6222546/2829009):

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients, File attachment) throws Exception {
    try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.setSubject(subject);

    MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    mbp1.setText(body);

    MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();
    FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(attachment);
    mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    mbp2.setFileName(fds.getName());

    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
    mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);

    message.setContent(mp);

    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
    else
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
    Transport.send(message);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

usage:

```
sendMail("Subject", "Body text", "test@test.com", "test1@test.com", new File("/mnt/sdcard/ExcelFile.xls"));
```

Comment: thank you @Manu, but I have found another solution which allow to know if the message was sent or not and is received in real time which is not the case for the code of the post in which I have to wait to receive messages especially when receiver is a gmail account

Answer (score 0):

I just find this link which allow to send mail with attachment programmaticaly using only one class

here it is :

```
    import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;

    public Mail() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
        // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
                .getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public Mail(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
                && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
                && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_multipart);

            // send email
            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    public String[] get_to() {
        return _to;
    }

    public void setTo(String[] _to) {
        this._to = _to;
    }

    public String get_from() {
        return _from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String _from) {
        this._from = _from;
    }

    public String get_subject() {
        return _subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String _subject) {
        this._subject = _subject;
    }



    // more of the getters and setters …..
}
```

and here is an example of using it :

```
new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Utils.getProgressDialog(CheckedListActivity.this);
        }

        boolean success = false;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Mail m = new Mail("username@gmail.com", "password"); 

              String[] toArr = {"sdfdfvg@gmail.com", "sdcfsdfdsf@hotmail.com"}; 
              m.setTo(toArr); 
              m.setFrom("username@gmail.com"); 
              m.setSubject("MyApp COMMANDE TEST"); 
              m.setBody("MyApp COMMANDE TEST contenu"); 

              try { 
                m.addAttachment("/sdcard/MyAPP/liste_clients.xls"); 

                if(m.send()) { 
                    success = true;                 
                } else { 
                    success = false;                      
                } 
              } catch(Exception e) {                   
                Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
              } 
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Utils.dismissProgressDialog();

            if(success){
                Utils.showAlertDialog(CheckedListActivity.this, "Envoi reussi", "Votre message est envoyé avec succée");
            }else{
                Utils.showAlertDialog(CheckedListActivity.this, "Echec d'envoi", "Votre message n'est pas envoyé, veuillez ressayer");
            }


        }

    }.execute();
```

and the mail is received in real time which is not the case for the other class

here is the src link :  [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

and of course we have to add those jar :

[mail](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/mail.jar)

[activation](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/activation.jar)

[additionnal](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/additionnal.jar)

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks,..  your code help its working fine.. But when i attached file from sdcard I am getting error file not found...
 m.addAttachment("/mnt/sdcard/test.jpg"); Plese help me.

Comment: solve issue using this.

String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
          File mFolder = new File(extr + "/Download/10.jpg");
    m.addAttachment(mFolder,"10.jpg"); 
Hope this will help someone.. 
Thanks