# Java Mail API - Datasource from URL - getting error

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, javax.activation

Am integrating JavaMailAPI in my webapplication. I have to embed images in the html body. Am trying to get the images from the src/main/resource directory instead of hard code the image path.

Please find the below code that am trying.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("email/logo_email.png");

MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String htmlText = "<img src=\"cid:image\">" + "<H1>Dear Customer</H1>";
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

try {
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource fds = new URLDataSource(url);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(message);
System.out.println("Done");
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Am getting the below error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.activation.URLDataSource.getContentType(URLDataSource.java:78)
at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContentType(DataHandler.java:205)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1245)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1001)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:333)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1255)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2012)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:1980)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:97)
```

Comment: are you using servlet ?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005983/sending-email-with-attachment-through-gmailsender

Comment: yes am using @WebServlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is worked for me to this requirement.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(new 
File(classLoader.getResource("email/logo_email.png").getFile()));
```